# What would be a good practice for a REST endpoint that helps with decisions

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Lets say I have the following endpoint:

```
/operations/needed
```

Which will have two responses:

1. Operation is needed
2. Operation is not needed

What would be a good practice for the response?
Here is some I am think about:

A

```
{"operationNeeded":true}
```

B

```
OK->Not needed
Bad_request->Needed
```

C

```
{"operation":"/operations"} -> Needed
{"operation":null} -> Not needed
```

Which one would be preferred? (Why?)
Keep in mind that for better or worse we are not using HATEOAS type of responses anywhere else.

Comment: My opinion is that, of those choices, A is clearest and is what I'd use.

Comment: A if you need to just respond with yes/no. C if you need to respond with list of what's needed (and then `[]` would be better than `null`, for consistency). B if you want to ignore what `400 BAD REQUEST` is supposed to mean (who needs standards, right? :P ).

Comment: I've seen the BAD REQUEST one implemented  like that. I know it's not okey but wanted to include it.

Comment: B is not desirable since it's saying "bad request" even though the request isn't bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is optimized for *large grain* hypermedia transfer (think "web pages").  Trying to communicate a single bit of information really isn't the sweet spot.

One common approach is to notice that HTTP can distinguish between "does not exist" and "empty".  When a resource is empty, we can either send a [200](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) response with a content-length header, or we can send a [204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) with no entity body at all.  When the resource has no representation available, then [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) is appropriate.

So you will find API that use the 204/404 to indicate whether or not a flag is set.

[Github's Starring API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#check-if-you-are-starring-a-repository) is an example that takes this approach.

It's also fine to treat it like a resource with a representation that changes depending on whether or not the bit is set.

Your `C` approach is probably the most "RESTful" of the set -- it's normal to provide/remove *links* to other resources as a way of communicating to the REST client which application state transitions are currently available.  Again, think web page -- there is a "page 2" link only when there are more items to look at, no "next" link when you are already at the end, and so on.  It's the HATEOAS approach.

But all of them are "fine".